# Python selenium how to find an element by class if it contains a space at the end?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Python selenium how to find an element by class if it contains a space at the end?

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ui-table__row table__row--selected ')))
```

python doesn't find it.I know that you can't use spaces in a class name. But how then to search for this class?

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ui-table__row table__row--selected ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find by `CSS_SELECTOR` assuming this class is under a `div`

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ui-table__row.table__row--selected')))
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are specific above using `CLASS_NAME` locator, you can just remove the whitespace at the end, and replace the whitespace between class names with a dot(`.`). See below:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ui-table__row.table__row--selected')))
```

- Or if you want to use `XPATH` locator, you can retain whitespace and construct expression as below:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'ui-table__row table__row--selected ')]")))
```